# Rails/Devise No Flash Messages Generate on Incorrect Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, flash, devise

Trying to make it such that Devise will generate flash error messages on incorrect signup. For instance "Email can't be blank" or "Password is too short".

When reviewing railscast episode 210 this seems to be out of the box functionality for Devise (via validatable) but in my instance no flash messages generate for signup. Note flash messages do generate in other instances of this app such as sending reset instructions, deleting account, etc... (behavior can be seen on production website ninjaspeak.com if you want to see for yourself)

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Using Devise 2.1.2 with Rails 3.2.13

devise.en.yml:

```
# Additional translations at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n

en:
  errors:
    messages:
      expired: "has expired, please request a new one"
      not_found: "not found"
      already_confirmed: "was already confirmed, please try signing in"
      not_locked: "was not locked"
      not_saved:
        one: "1 error prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"
        other: "%{count} errors prohibited this %{resource} from being saved:"

  devise:
    failure:
      already_authenticated: 'You are already signed in.'
      unauthenticated: 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      unconfirmed: 'You have to confirm your account before continuing.'
      locked: 'Your account is locked.'
      invalid: 'Invalid email or password.'
      invalid_token: 'Invalid authentication token.'
      timeout: 'Your session expired, please sign in again to continue.'
      inactive: 'Your account was not activated yet.'
    sessions:
      signed_in: ''
      signed_out: ''
    passwords:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to reset your password in a few minutes.'
      updated: 'Your password was changed successfully. You are now signed in.'
      updated_not_active: 'Your password was changed successfully.'
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your e-mail exists on our database, you will receive a password recovery link on your e-mail"
    confirmations:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes.'
      send_paranoid_instructions: 'If your e-mail exists on our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes.'
      confirmed: 'Your NinjaSpeak account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in.'
    registrations:
      signed_up: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
      signed_up_but_unconfirmed: 'A message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the link to activate your NinjaSpeak account.'
      signed_up_but_inactive: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is not yet activated.'
      signed_up_but_locked: 'You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is locked.'
      updated: 'You updated your account successfully.'
      update_needs_confirmation: "You updated your account successfully, but we need to verify your new email address. Please check your email and click on the confirm link to finalize confirming your new email address."
      destroyed: 'Your NinjaSpeak account was successfully cancelled.'
    unlocks:
      send_instructions: 'You will receive an email with instructions about how to unlock your account in a few minutes.'
      unlocked: 'Your account has been unlocked successfully. Please sign in to continue.'
      send_paranoid_instructions: 'If your account exists, you will receive an email with instructions about how to unlock it in a few minutes.'
    omniauth_callbacks:
      success: 'Successfully authorized from %{kind} account.'
      failure: 'Could not authorize you from %{kind} because "%{reason}".'
    mailer:
      confirmation_instructions:
        subject: 'Confirmation instructions'
      reset_password_instructions:
        subject: 'Reset password instructions'
      unlock_instructions:
        subject: 'Unlock Instructions'
```

application.html.erb:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :natives_language, :next_language, :remember_me, :bookmark
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  validates_presence_of :natives_language, :next_language
end
```

Edit to show css:

```
#flash_alert {
padding-top: 16px;
float: right;
}

#flash_notice {
padding-top: 16px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: show us the create action in sessions_controller.rb..

Comment: I don't have a sessions_controller.rb file, the app just uses the default controllers devise utilizes in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb file.

Underneath

`<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

I had to add the devise error messages helper:

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
```

Now flash messages appear on invalid signup like 'Email can't be blank', 'Password doesn't match confirmation', etc...

Answer (score 2):

### Answering Question

---

As far as i know, devise does not manage the errors for validations, that is why you can't do that, and in my humble opinion i don't see it like a good behavior. So i would recommend you to use the normal display for validation errors.

If you want to improve the validation messages to validate them on the client side, without reaching the 
server you can use the "[jquery-validation-rails](https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails)" and add to the application.js or another javascript file something like this:

### validation_jquery.js

```
//validador jquery
$('#new_user').validate({
  rules: {
    'user[password]': {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 100
    },
    'user[email]': {
      required: true, 
      email: true, 
      maxlength: 150
    }
  },
  messages: {
    'user[password]': {
        required: "Required Field",
        maxlength: "Name too big, max size 100"
    },
    'user[email]': {
        required: "Required Field",
        email: "Invalid email",
        maxlength: "Email too big, max size 150"
    }
  }
});
```

And if you want to change the color of the error message you can do it with css

### validation_jquery.css

```
/* Change color to error messages for validation with jQuery */
label.error{
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
```

### User Model

```
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :password, 
            presence: true, 
            length: { maximum: 100 }

  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 150 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
```

### ---------------------------

### Improving alert messages

---

### Regular Rails Messages

I like to use this way to catch flash messages in rails, it has an "X" button at the right with the text "close" to make it more UX.

```
<!-- Flash Notice for Rails notifications -->
  <% if notice %>
    <p class="alert alert-success">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only" style="font-size: 14px !important;"> Close</span></button>
      <%= notice %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <p class="alert alert-danger">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only" style="font-size: 14px !important;"> Close</span></button>
      <%= alert %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

### Super Cool Growlyflash Messages

Also, you can use in Rails 3 or 4.1 a gem called "[growlyflash](https://github.com/estum/growlyflash)" which enables a growly message style to flash messages, and make it look cool. If you use growlyflash you don't need the code for flash messages, instead you will use this in your "application.html.erb":

```
<%= growlyflash_static_notices %>
```

And if you want to make the message disappear when clicked, just need to add this javascript in a file called "growlyflash.js" (just to keep the code organized). Also i add a way to solve an issue with the danger message color.

### Growlyflash.js

```
// The message will disappear when get clicked
jQuery(function() {
  $(document).on('click.alert.data-api', '[data-dismiss="alert"]', function(e) {
    return e.stopPropagation();
  });
  return $(document).on('touchstart click', ".bootstrap-growl", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('[data-dismiss="alert"]', this).click();
    return false;
  });
});


// This part of code is VERY IMPORTANT, because it solved an issue for rendering color
// to the danger message.
$.bootstrapGrowl.defaults = $.extend(true, {}, $.bootstrapGrowl.defaults, {
  type_mapping: {
    alert: 'warning',
    error: 'danger',
    notice: 'info',
    success: 'success'
  }
});
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Demi! I'm definitely checking out Growlyflash.

Comment: i'm glad that you find it useful :D

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be as simple as you haven't applied any CSS styling to your alert container (if you inspect your DOM when you think a flash message should have appeared you will probably find its there).

Below is what i use for my flash messages based upon the type of message i want to output

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= name.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```